# Android StackView inside ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, stackview

I try to make `StackView` touchtable inside `ScrollView`. Finnaly I make `CustomStackView` which extends `StackView` and override `dispatchTouchEvent` where I disallow touch event in parent (which is `ScrollView`).

```
public class CustomStackView extends StackView {

public CustomStackView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomStackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomStackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
    }
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

    return true;
}
}
```

It works but is a little bit hackish. Have you got any other idea?